# 1st column has YY (Year) and 2nd column has MMDD (Month,Date)

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to extract data based on two columns, the 1st column has YY (year) data and 2nd column had MMDD (month,date).

How would i write my sql statement to extract data starting from year 13 month december till date.

Comment: Step 1 - Decide what century you want.

Comment: Offer some examples of what you have tried, some table structures... something more than what you have given us, we are here to help solve the problem not do it for you.

Comment: I TRIED DOING THIS    SELECT * FROM
TABLE WHERE TABLE.A>=13 AND TABLE.B>=1201;

Comment: We need to know the data types and possibly sizes of the two columns before we can guess how it can be done. If the columns are VARCHAR, it'll be very different from NUMERIC or maybe even CHAR. It's not enough simply to tell us what the columns represent.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
    from table1
    where (
           (yy='13' and substring(mmdd, 1, 2) = '12') or 

           (
           yy>'13' and yy < cast(year(CURDATE() as varchar) 
           ) or

           (
           yy>'13' and yy = cast(year(CURDATE() as varchar) and  substring(mmdd, 1, 2) < cast(month(CURDATE() as varchar) 
           ) or

           (
           yy>'13' and yy = cast(year(CURDATE() as varchar) and  substring(mmdd, 1, 2) = cast(month(CURDATE() as varchar) and  substring(mmdd, 3, 4) <= cast(day(CURDATE() as varchar) 
           )
          )
```

Comment: But that doesnt give me data till present date.